# How can be improved these UML diagram for an iphone shopping cart application? (sqlite, parsxml delegate, httprequest)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop, sqlite, uml

The diagrams below are my very first attempt at creating a class diagram, the use case diagram and sequence diagram describing a simple iPhone shopping cart application which get the data from web database(MySQL) and save it within SQLite.

i am not completely certain about them but I'm hoping to learn from you guys how you would design it. I'm particularly interested in your use of design patterns and which patterns you would use, how you would implement it in the design, and why.
[image][image]

[Original size of sequence diagram](http://www.mandanemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/SequenceDiagram.png)[image]

Comment: What application did you use to create these UML diagrams--please!

Comment: i have used VioletUML, you can downloaded within this link http://sourceforge.net/projects/violet/files/latest/download

Comment: yUML is great for UML diagrams http://yUML.me

Comment: @EllNeal one of the problem of VioletUml is that you have to do redundancy in write method again for example if you create class diagram you have also to enter the name of the method manually within sequence diagram again, but rational roze does this automatically for you, do you know yUML.me do it automatically or no?

Comment: hehe... do you have any comment about my UML Digrams?

Comment: Not sure this is a question, you are asking to learn (good), you are asking for a diagram (ok?), is there a right answer (nope).  Your title is a not a question but a string of words with a question mark at the end.  Try refining the question or better yet take a stab/try at it and ask people for ideas/improvements/flaws or effectiveness in communicating the solution.

Comment: @TedJohnson , well, i will revise my question, but what is you opinion? i have already implemented this iphone application, but do you think is there any problem inside this diagrams?

Comment: Usecase should have a specific goal. Navigate Client is a poor usecase.  View Product is probably your core usecase with Find By Category and Find By Brand being seperate usecases.  That include it.  Your two Add to ... case are probaly extensions of that not includes as they are now.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSpamer now, i have revised it, what is your opinion about other ulm diagram? i have a problem with Rational Roze, since i can not dram a condition within sequence diagram of Rational Roze?

Comment: Your Actor should probably link to your two 'View Product By...' and Your two 'Add to ...' should <extend>  View Product.  Then you should then have a sequence diagram for each usecase.

Answer (score 1):

The diagrams are suitable for an overview of your design.

To improve them and convey details, you need to break the application into subsystems, each one modeled separately.

Based on what is known, I suggest three subsystems:

- Shopping
- Persistence
- Web services

When you complete the partitioning, you can make one set of simpler overview diagrams showing only interactions between subsystems.